# How do I prove or disprove that the series are Fourier transformation for some function: $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{\cos 2k x}{\sqrt{2k \ln 2k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Let's say, there is a sum $\Sigma^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{\cos 2k x}{\sqrt{2k \ln 2k}}$, how do I prove or disprove that it is a Fourier transformation for some function? Any ideas or online sources are welcome.

Comment: None of the terms in the sum depend on $n$

Comment: @Andrei Ok, now I corrected my mistake. The summation index should be $k$.

Comment: Every function is the Fourier transform of its anti transform, provided the transform exist (in some sense). For example if the function is in $L^2$.